# The value of $\sin(nx\pi)/ \sin(x \pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose that we want to calculate the value of $$\frac{\sin(56\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}$$ What is my mistake in the following calculations?

First Try using identity sin(a+b): $$\frac{\sin(56\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{\sin(28 \pi +28\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{2\sin(28 \pi) \cos(28\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{4\sin(14\pi)\cos(14\pi) \cos(28\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=4$$

Second Try using sin(2kpi +x)=sin(x):
$$\frac{\sin(56\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{\sin(28 \pi +28\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{\sin(28 \pi) }{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{\sin(14 \pi +14 \pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}=\frac{\sin(14 \pi) }{\sin(14 \pi)}=1$$

A third try can be done with limits, using Del Hospital where we will get 4 as an answer. Which is correct and why?

Thanks and Merry Christmas

Comment: Merry Christmas as well ! The mistake as that we divide by $0$. The expression is undefined.

Comment: $\frac{\sin(56\pi)}{\sin(14 \pi)}$ is simply undefined!

Comment: You can say $\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\sin(56x)}{\sin(14x)}=\lim_{x\to\pi}4\cos(14x)\cos(28x)=4,\,\lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\sin(14x+42\pi)}{\sin(14x)}=\lim_{x\to\pi}1=1$.

Comment: Title and body are different

Comment: $L'Hopital$ is for limits of expressions of a certain form. The expression you wrote is a fraction without any variables, $L'Hopital$ does not apply. In your title you had a variable but in the body of the question it became missing. You should clarify which of the two versions you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Correctly using limits,

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin(56\theta)}{\sin(14\theta)}=4$$

and

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin(28\pi+28\theta)}{\sin(14\theta)}=\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin(28\theta)}{\sin(14\theta)}=2$$

and

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin(42\pi+14\theta)}{\sin(14\theta)}=\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin(14\pi+14\theta)}{\sin(14\theta)}=\lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin(14\theta)}{\sin(14\theta)}=1.$$

Yet another explanation of why the pseudo-expression $\dfrac00$ is indeterminate.